# Wordpress permanent links not working (the weird way)

Tags: permalinks

I have just moved my dev wordpress to its new home, and something very weird happened:

Some, just some, of the links are not working (for example, the domain.com/contact page is not working while other pages are working). They are all pages (and some are categories links as well), some working, some not, no pattern it seems.

I wonder if there is something wrong with the host, godaddy (the host) is infamous with this it seems. But usually the whole thing should not work, here we have some work, some dont't.

Any idea will greatly help.

PS: by not working, I meant I was show godaddy default 404 pages. How does this happen I dont even understand.

PS again: dang it, I found out why. I have a file named contact.php, after i renamed it old.contact.php it seems to work now. Weird, I mean the htaccess redirection rules should not match contact/ with contact.php right? Is it just goddady or ?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened probably because you have …

```
Options +MultiViews
```

… somewhere in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`. If there is no directory `/contact/` Apache will look for a file with this name and `MultiViews` matches partial files names. In general `MultiViews` and WordPress don’t work well together.